# Find and replace key from array in react native

Tags: react-native, listview, checkbox

I am trying to implement checked and unchecked box in a flatlist.

I have taken a keyword checked. On the basis of this keyword I want to show the checkbox (checked or unchecked)

I am trying to update the checked key on selection and deselection.

But getting errors.

Can anyone tell me what is wrong here?

Here is my code:

```
updateItem(item) {
    this.setState({
      array :  ! this.array.findIndex(item => item.title === item.title).checked
    })
    this.setState({ array: [...this.array] });

}
```

My array is:

```
(this.array = [{title: "Option 1",checked:"false"},
      { title: "Option 2" ,checked:"false"},
      { title: "Option 3",checked:"false"},
      { title: "Option 4",checked:"false" },
      { title: "Option 5",checked:"false"}
    ])
```

Thanks!

Comment: What are the errors

Comment: @GokulKulkarni Its not updating the value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are setting the array to true or false at the moment!

Also be sure that your checked value is a `boolean` and not `string`

```js
this.array = [{title: "Option 1",checked:false},
      { title: "Option 2" ,checked:false},
      { title: "Option 3",checked:false},
      { title: "Option 4",checked:false },
      { title: "Option 5",checked:false}
]
```

This method will map over your array. If the title matches it will toggle the checked value else it will return the same object again.

```js
updateItem = (item) => {
    this.setState({
      array: this.state.array.map(curr => {
        if(item.title === curr.title) {
         return {...curr, checked: !curr.checked}
        } else {
         return curr
        }
      })
    })
}
```

Comment: I think both same item variable create an issue. I have replace dit with:
updateItem = (item) => {
    this.setState({
      array : this.state.array.map(itemObj => {
        if(item.title === itemObj.title) {
         return {...item, checked: !item.checked}
        } else {
         return item
        }
      })
    })
}

Is it correct?

Comment: sorry. yes exactly :) should be fine now

Comment: Tobias, you the legend

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code,

```
this.state.array = [{title: "Option 1",checked:false},
      { title: "Option 2" ,checked:false},
      { title: "Option 3",checked:false},
      { title: "Option 4",checked:false },
      { title: "Option 5",checked:false}
]
```

change **this.array** to **this.state.array**, in your constructor. if you
are doing in any other function then you have to use setState

And while updating,

```
updateItem = (item) => {
    this.setState({
      array : this.state.array.map(item => {
        if(item.title === item.title) {
         return {...item, checked: !item.checked};
        } else {
         return { ...item, checked: false }; // if you want only one checked
         // return item; if multiple checks if fine.
        }
      })
    })
}
```

Comment: I have another question can you please check that - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57605059/react-native-array-updates/57605155?noredirect=1#comment101667160_57605155