# React Native Array Updates

Tags: arrays, react-native

I have two arrays of objects which have properties that match (id & name).

```js
var result1 = [[
      { title: "Option 1", enable: false },
      { title: "Option 2", enable: false },
      { title: "Option 3", enable: false },
      { title: "Option 4", enable: false },
      { title: "Option 5", enable: false }
    ]
;
```

```js
var result2 = [
    { title: "Option 3", enable: false },
    { title: "Option 4", enable: false },
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
result1.map(item => {
  const isChecked = result2.some(({ title }) => title === item.title);
  return {
    ...item,
    checked: isChecked
  }
});
```

Comment: It says result2.some is not a function. result2.some is not defined

Comment: Are you able to show your whole code? Specifically where result1 and result2 are being defined.

Comment: Please check now

Comment: @Dan you are doing operation some on an array, there is no such array function.

Comment: @GokulKulkarni - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some

Answer (score -1):

Use the following code,

```
import _ from 'lodash';

this.setState({
    result1: this.state.result1.map(item => {
                   return (_.find(this.state.result2, item)) ? { ...itemObj, checked: true }: { ...itemObj, checked: false }; });
                   // return (_.find(this.state.result2, {'title': item.title})) ? { ...itemObj, checked: true }: { ...itemObj, checked: false }; }); // if you want to check only title
});
```

lodash is a lib which will be helpful in such things.

Detailed documentation for the same can be found in this [link](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15), for [find](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#find).

The above code with check the whole item object if you want to check only part of it say only title below is the code